# How can I set a SSL certificate for Google Maps Android API UrlTileProvider?

Tags: android, ssl, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2, wms

I want to set a custom SSL certificate for my UrlTileProvider from the Google Maps Android API.
In my subclassed UrlTileProvider I'm setting the URL to the WMS of my Geoserver by https.

Can you tell me how to set the SSLContext by UrlTileProvider in order to use my SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

if I do not set the SocketFactory directly to a specific connection - I can define my socket factory as the DefaultSSLSocketFactory for HttpsURLConnections in general.

See:
Instead of applying this function:

```
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

I can add the Socket Factory per Default:

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
                // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
                CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

                InputStream caInput = mContext.get().getAssets().
                        open("mycert.crt");
                Certificate ca;
                try {
                    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
                } finally {
                    caInput.close();
                }

                // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
                String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
                keyStore.load(null, null);
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

                // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
                String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
                TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
                tmf.init(keyStore);

                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```